# Is the stack in a cache?

Tags: performance, caching, memory, stack

In modern computers I know that the current code region is in a high-speed cache. However, in many computer language implementations the local (automatic) variables will be on the stack, so there will be a lot of memory accesses to the stack.

Is the stack in another cache in normal architectures?

If, not, suppose the stack could be relocated to be "local", ie very near to the current code segment, so that it would be within the cache being used for the code. Would this speed up memory access for automatic variables?

Comment: It is pretty much automatic, stack memory has very good locality of reference and is accessed a lot so it is always in the first-level cache.  In many language implementations, local variables are *not* on the stack frame but optimized to be stored in processor registers.  Which is the fastest memory available.

Comment: @HansPassant On an i7 processor in 32-bit mode there are 8 registers, 6 of which are available for locals. Since, in most cases at least 1 register is needed for swap and utility purposes, you generally will never get more than 5 registers used for locals. Therefore if your function has more than 5x4 (20) bytes of variables then, you will be using the stack for variable storage. A double requires 8 bytes of storage and is almost never implemented as a register variable. So every single double will be in memory. In the kind of program I write functions will often have a dozen doubles.

Comment: It isn't 1978 anymore.  A double will be stored in an XMM register or the FPU stack.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know what super computers you are working on, but when I get disassemblies of my code, most of my variables are located at EBP offsets, which means they are on the stack.

Comment: A stack is just memory. The processor has no knowledge if a memory access is to a stack or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most modern computers will cache memory indiscriminately, so whatever memory is accessed by the CPU will get cached. So, that includes the memory including the stack. In fact, the stack will be highly likely to be cached nearly all the time because it is frequently accessed.

The main concern with having the stack cached is that because it is modified so frequently, it can cause the cache to be out of sync with main memory and trigger a cache miss, which would damage performance. This generally does not happen because most architectures use what is called *write back cache*, which means that each block of cache, called the *cache line*, has a dirty bit and uses deferred copy of the cache back to main memory when required. This usually will result in relatively rare main memory updates and performance will be good.

Performance problems can arise, however, if two different threads attempt to write to the same memory. This can cause a *coherence miss*, resulting in a cache write and update to memory and lower performance. Normally, software is not structured such that two different threads would use the same stack. However, if this were to occur, then performance could be poor on some architectures because the conflicting stack accesses by the different threads would cause frequent cache misses.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, when you push a value from a CPU register to the stack, the value will first be cached in a hidden register. This is possible because modern CPU's (dating back at least 15 years) have more registers than register names, so there are unnamed registers which can be used for this.

Comment: nice answer, can you give one source on this subject of using hidden registers under the hood?

Comment: @AntoineWeber: What happens if you "push a value to the CPU stack" is that the CPU issues a write instruction from a register to memory, say from "register RAX". On a modern CPU, this write doesn't cause a delay, because the RAX _name_ is then used for another register, while the now-unnamed register continues holds the value that was in RAX. And the newest CPU's will reuse this unnamed register if you'd re-read the value from the stack - it might be renamed to RBX this time